# Android Emulator launches with errors

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

When I try to launch my AVD using Android Studio, I get error messages

`emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Starting AVD without boot animation.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Hax is enabled
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
WARNING: init: Missing WGL extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read`

and when my Emulator launches I see nothing there, just a black screen.

Could you assist me guys?

Answer (score 0):

You need enabled HAXM in your bios.